# Get tomorrows date from input

Tags: c#, .net

I need my code to get the next day via user input but at the moment it is just getting the next day from the current date. I do have a addDays which is already working but I am not sure how to get the next day via entering any day.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace nextdate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Today's date to get next date");
            Console.Read(); // user inputs data
            Console.ReadLine();
            date currentdate = new date("");  
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", currentdate.getDay());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class date {
            public string day;    
            public int month;    
            public int year;

            public date(string day){  
                this.day = day;
            }

            public string getDay(){
                day = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToString("dd");                 
                return day;                      
            }

            public int getMonth(){            
                month = DateTime.Today.Month;
                return month;
            }

            public int getYear(){           
                year = DateTime.Today.Year;
                return year;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you wanted to get is tomorrow's day part of the date. If today is 25/12/2015( 25th dec 2015). You want to see the result as 26. Is this correct.

Its easier to just create an extension method instead of creating a class. 
However, here is an example using your class in a simplified version.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Today's date in dd/mm/yyyy to get next date ");
        var userDate = Console.ReadLine();
        MyDate currentdate = new MyDate(userDate);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", currentdate.GetTomorrowDate());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class MyDate
    {
        public DateTime day;
        public MyDate(string inputDate)
        {
            this.day = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        public string GetTomorrowDate()
        {
            return day.AddDays(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct but I want to see the result after the user has typed in a day within the console. E.g. if a user types in 02/06/2015 then what should be displayed is 03/06/2015

Comment: I have made changes to the solution. If you type in 02/06/2015, it should return 03/06/2015. Give it a a try

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "DateTime.Today" in your getDay() but instead convert the user's input data (string) to (DateTime) data type then you will be able to AddDays after the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your day member variable to form the user input date and return the next day from it. Please refer the below updated code :

```
public string getDay(){
int dateTimeDay;
var currentDate = DateTime.Today;
if int32.TryParse(this.day, out dateTimeDay) 
{
    retrun new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, datetimeDay).AddDays(1).Day.ToString();
}
else
{
     retrun currentDate.AddDays(1).Day.ToString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your requirement is to get a Date from user and display day, month, year etc for next day. You can do it like below:

```
class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
    {
        //Format is given by 'dd-MM-yyyy'. You can change it to the one you want like 'dd/MM/yyyy' in below two lines and in 'GetTomorrowDateInStringFormat' method.
        //Then user will have to enter date in the given format
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Today's date to get next date (dd-MM-yyyy)");
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var currentdate = new Date(date);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", currentdate.GetDay());
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", currentdate.GetMonth());
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", currentdate.GetYear());
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", currentdate.GetTomorrowDateInStringFormat()); //Call to newly added method
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Date
    {
        public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
        public string Day;
        public int Month;
        public int Year;

        public Date(DateTime date)
        {
            MyDate = date;
        }

        public string GetDay()
        {
            Day = MyDate.AddDays(1).ToString("dd");
            return Day;
        }

        public int GetMonth()
        {
            Month = MyDate.AddDays(1).Month;
            return Month;
        }

        public int GetYear()
        {
            Year = MyDate.AddDays(1).Year;
            return Year;
        }

        public string GetTomorrowDateInStringFormat() //Added new method to return tomorrow's date in string format
        {
            return MyDate.AddDays(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. Will this take leap years into account since I am using a DateTime?

Comment: You have that method parseExact how do I use multiple formats instead of one? Such as "MM/dd/yyyy". I have tried setting an array type string which holds the different formats and inserted that but it is still not working. I would also need the output to be the same format as what the user types in for an input. Thanks

Comment: You need to identify the format and set the IFormatProvider accordingly. To convert the output in the same format you can use 'DateTime.ToString("Format_String")' method where Format_String will be same which was used for input.